# Calculated Fields in Tableau

Tags: calculated-field, tableau-desktop

Suppose "ABC" is my dimension and it has categories "a", "b", and "c". In tableau, I have the following calculated field:

IF [ABC] = "a" THEN 1 ELSEIF [ABC]= "b" THEN 2 ELSE 3 END

This calculated field shows up in the measures section. However, I would like it to show up in the dimensions section so that I can sort by these numbers. In other words, I am trying to numerate the original data while still being able to use it the same way. Does anyone know how to make the calculated field show up in dimensions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried converting the the calculated field to dimension?

Answer (score 1):

You can just drag the calculated field from measures to dimensions panel.

Please consider that if you made this dimension only for sorting you can use a manual sorting option [as described in this guide](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sorting_computed_howto.htm#:%7E:text=the%20field%20type.-,Manual,-lets%20you%20select).

Comment: and you might want to learn about CASE statements also